# Feature Selection using Stacking Ensemble?

Tags: feature-selection, ensemble-learning, stacking

I want to combine some estimators, such as `Logistic Regression`, `Gaussian NB` and `K-Nearest Neighbors` for `Features Selection`, I tried to use `StackingClassifier()` estimator to do that, but there is no `feature_importances_` attribute for this estimator.

Is there any other method to select features combining those classifiers ??

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a Stacking classifier I would recommend to change the feature selection algorithm to [PermutationImportance](http://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/user_guide/evaluate/feature_importance_permutation/), which is model agnostic way of computing importance based on random repeated permutation, but in this case you will have to provide a metric (accuracy, roc_auc, etc.) to measure the decrease on performance when a feature is shuffled, i.e the more the metric decreases when feature F is shuffled, the more important the feature is for the model.

Comment: This is actually a good idea!